# The PyQt button does not show up

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

So....I am using the PyQt lib for python to make a Graphics class which abstracts away most of the features of the QtGui class.I"ll be using it later for my other projects.This seems to be working fine,except that the button and the other widgets do not show up,although the window gets created.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Graphics:
    def __init__(self):

        self.app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.widgets={}
        self.labels={}
        self.buttons={}


    def getApp(self):

        return self.app


    def newWidget(self,name:str):

        self.widgets[name]=QtGui.QWidget()
        return self.widgets[name]       


    def addButton(self,name:str,text:str):

        self.buttons[name]=QtGui.QPushButton(text)
        return self.buttons[name]


    def addLabel(self,name:str,text:str):

        self.labels[name]=QtGui.QLabel()
        self.labels[name].setText(text)
        return self.labels[name]


    def start(self):
        for widget in self.widgets:
            self.widgets[widget].show()
        sys.exit(self.app.exec_())
```

^ That's the code.Down below shows how i implement the class

```
from graphics import Graphics

gui=Graphics()
w1=gui.newWidget("hmm")
bt1=gui.addButton("hey","hello")
print(bt1)
gui.start()
```

It'd be great if you could provide insight as to why this is happening.Thank You

Comment: Do you want the button to be displayed in the widget or separately? If there are 2 widgets and a button is added to which widget should belong?

Comment: Is there a method to add a button to a certain widget?I looked up a PyQt tutorial,and they were only using a single widget,so i couldn't learn further

Comment: So I ask you if we say that you have added 2 widgets with newWidget() and then you want to add a button with addButton() that button where should it be shown in the first or second widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Qt there is a basic rule: the `QWidget` children are drawn with respect to the parent `QWidget`, and if it does not have a parent this will be a window, which is called top-level.

Another concept is `QPushButton`, `QLabel`, `QSpinBox`, etc. are `QWidgets` since they inherit from this class.

So, since `QPushButton` does not have a parent, it should show itself as a window, and for that you should use `show()`:

```
def start(self):
    [w.show() for name, w in self.widgets.items()]
    [button.show() for name, button in self.buttons.items()]
    [label.show() for name, label in self.labels.items()]

    sys.exit(self.app.exec_())
```

[image]

---

If your intention is that some `QLabel` or `QPushButton` be part of some `QWidget` then we must indicate that widget as parent, for example in my next solution I propose to add the name of the widget, and if the widget does not exist it should be created:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Graphics:
    def __init__(self):
        self.app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.widgets={}
        self.labels={}
        self.buttons={}

    def getApp(self):
        return self.app

    def newWidget(self, name:str):
        w = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.widgets[name] = w
        return w     

    def addButton(self, widget_name:str, name:str, text:str):
        if widget_name in self.widgets:
            w = self.widgets[widget_name]
        else:
            w = self.newWidget(widget_name)
        button = QtGui.QPushButton(text, parent=w)
        self.buttons[name] = button
        return button

    def addLabel(self, widget_name:str, name:str, text:str):
        if widget_name in self.widgets:
            w = self.widgets[widget_name]
        else:
            w = self.newWidget(widget_name)
        label = QtGui.QLabel(text, parent=w)
        self.labels[name] = label
        return label

    def start(self):
        [w.show() for name, w in self.widgets.items()]

        sys.exit(self.app.exec_())
```

[image]

---

If you want to add a parent after the button is created then you can use `setParent()`:

**graphics.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Graphics:
    def __init__(self):
        self.app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.widgets={}
        self.labels={}
        self.buttons={}

    def getApp(self):
        return self.app

    def newWidget(self, name:str):
        w = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.widgets[name] = w
        return w     

    def addButton(self, name:str, text:str):
        button = QtGui.QPushButton(text)
        self.buttons[name] = button
        return button

    def addLabel(self, name:str, text:str):
        label = QtGui.QLabel(text)
        self.labels[name] = label
        return label

    def start(self):
        for _, w in in self.widgets.items():
            w.show()
        sys.exit(self.app.exec_())
```

**main.py**

```
gui=Graphics()
w1 = gui.newWidget("hmm")
bt1 = gui.addButton("hey","hello")
bt1.setParent(w1) # <-- set w1 as parent of bt1
gui.start()
```

Comment: added two more lines to the code:-
      for button in self.buttons:
   self.buttons[button].show()
still does not work

Comment: One more question,how do i add the widget as a parent to my button.Thanks again.

Comment: that worked quite nicely!So that's how i add a widget as the parent class.That helped me a lot.But can i  add the the same widget i created at the very first as a parent?

Comment: @user7657046 Then will you just create calls to newWidget()?

Comment: @user7657046 If you are going to create just one widget then why do you create the self.widgets dictionary?

Comment: in the following line: `button = QtGui.QPushButton(text, w)` where `w` is parent widget. It is not a parent class, but a parent widget.

Comment: i created a dictionary so that i could hide or show widgets at will.Not just one button or label,but a group of those

Comment: @user7657046 If my answer helps you, do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it, review the [tour], that is the best way to thank.

Comment: yep i do know how to mark it correct,i am just busy at work.Would have done it when i got home.Thanks again!